# Create keyboard shortcut that includes "Alt" not to be triggered by pressing "Escape"

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

I've created the following mapping in `~/.zshrc`

```
bindkey -s '^[u' 'whatever string'
```

and I have enabled `vim` mode by setting the following rule in `~/.zshrc`

```
bindkey -v
```

The problem I'm having is present when I'm in insert mode and I want to go to normal mode. If I press `Escape` then `u`, `whatever string` is appended to the command prompt at the cursor position. This implies that whenever I press `Escape`, the only key I mustn't press is `u` in order to go to normal mode. Otherwise I would append `whatever string`.

So, my question is, how can I map `Alt + u` to append `whatever string` so that it is not also toggled by pressing `Escape` then `u`.

**PD1**: Please note that this is a minimal working example.

**PD2**: The workaround I'm using at this moment is to press `Escape + {no map} + u` (where `{no map}` is a key which hasn't been mapped together with `Alt`)

Comment: Another workaround is to play with `KEYTIMEOUT`, eg. `KEYTIMEOUT=1` (= if `^[` and `u` don't come together within `KEYTIMEOUT` 100ths of secs -- as they do when they're produced by Alt-u, the binding is not considered). Unless you're using `zsh` on a REAL serial line which is also very slow, there's very little reason to use anything else: even with a flaky ssh connection, I don't think that the `^[u` sequence will be split in 2 different packets ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time that it comes to the terminal transmitting characters down the (virtual) wire to the host, there *is no difference* between the key sequence <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> and the key chord <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, or even the compound key sequence <kbd>⎈ Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd>.

They all get encoded as the `␛` character followed by the `u` character.  The Z shell sees no difference in the input character stream coming from the terminal, and can make no distinction.  Terminal I/O applications see characters, not keys.

Comment: You are right. This is the workaround I will be using: Since <kbd>u</kbd> is a key that have a meaning in the `vicmd` keymap from `zsh` I have created the following keymap instead `bindkey -s '^[U' 'whatever string'` (<kbd>U</kbd> instead of <kbd>u</kbd>.) Thus, since <kbd>u</kbd> hasn't been mapped together with <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd> doesn't append anything when pressing it after <kbd>Esc</kbd> has been pressed.

Comment: As a heuristic, applications can generally tell the difference between Alt+U and ESC, u by measuring the time in between the `\e` and `u` character are received though. See the `$KEYTIMEOUT` special variable in `zsh`, expressed in centiseconds.

Answer (score 4):

As [@JdeBP said](/a/567628), these days terminals send the same sequence of characters when the user presses <kbd>Escape</kbd> followed by <kbd>u</kbd> as when they press <kbd>u</kbd> while holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key: U+001B U+0075 (`\eu`).

However, in the case of <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>, they send both characters at once, while in the <kbd>Escape</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd> case, there is a delay between the `\e` and `u` characters are sent because users don't press both characters at the same time, so applications can generally tell the difference.

In the case of `zsh`'s line editor, when there's a key binding for both `x` and `xy`, the one for `x` is triggered when `y` has not been received within `$KEYTIMEOUT` centiseconds after `x` has been received, or a character other than `y` is received.

The default value of `$KEYTIMEOUT` is 40, that is 0.4 seconds. That is a value that allows users to enter multi-characters bindings by hand, but you can make it small enough that it's not humanly possible to enter key sequences this fast to make sure that multi-characters bindings are only triggered when generated from the pressing of key-combinations or function keys.

For instance, if you change `$KEYTIMEOUT` to 1 (0.01 seconds), then you'd need to type <kbd>u</kbd> very quickly after <kbd>Escape</kbd> for your `\eu` binding to trigger.

That's not limited to zsh. Most interactive terminal applications that allow customized key bindings have an equivalent setting. For instance, in `readline` (the line editor used by `bash`, `python`, `gdb`...), that's the `keyseq-timeout` variable (0.5 second by default); with `ncurses`, see the `ESCDELAY` variable and environment variable (1 second by default); with `vim`, see the `tm`/`ttm` options (1 second by default).